# Pass anonymous function object to std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, most-vexing-parse

Here is my question:
I define a functor:

```
class A { 
 public: 
   int operator()(int a, int b) const{
    return a + b;
   }
 };
typedef function<int (int, int)> Fun;
```

then I use a anonymous functor to create a std::function object, and I find something strange. Here is my code:

```
Fun f(A());
f(3, 4);
```

Unfortunately it is wrong. The error message is:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘A (*)()’ [-fpermissive]
error: too many arguments to function ‘Fun f(A (*)())’
```

However, when I change my code as follow:

```
A a;
Fun f(a);
f(3, 4);
```

or

```
Fun f = A();
f(3, 4);
```

The result is right. 
So, why is it? Help me understand it,please. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Fun f(A());
```

This is a case of the [most-vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It declares a function `f` which returns a `Fun`. It takes a function pointer as an argument, pointing at a function that takes no arguments and returns an `A`.

There are a few ways to get around this:

```
Fun f{A()};    // Uniform-initialisation syntax
Fun f{A{}};    // Uniform-initialisation on both objects
Fun f((A()));  // Forcing the initialiser to be an expression, not parameter list
```

Or one of the things you did.

Comment: You beat me to it. Most-vexing parse problem indeed.

Comment: Sometimes, terms in computer science are named in ways that mislead.  This is not one of those times.